# How to store sparse matrix?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, sparse-matrix

I need to implement 2 types of storing sparse matrix in C++:

- Linked List
- Array (effective way)

Space complexity is very important here. What are the most effective ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nnz` : non-zero number of sparse matrix
`row_size` : matrix row number
`column_size` : matrix column number
There are many ways, their space complexity :

- Compressed Sparse Row (CSR)  : `2*nnz + row_size` number of memory
- Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) : `2*nnz + column_size` number of  memory
- Coordinate Format (COO) : `3*nnz` number of  memory

For space complexity :
If `row_size > column_size`, use `CSC` format, otherwise, use `CSR` format.

For Time complexity:
For `CSR` format, Row will be indexed by `O(1)` time, Column will be indexed by `O(log(k))` time, by binary search the Column, `k` is the number of non-zero element of that row. So value will be indexed by `O(log(k))` time.
For `COO` format, value will be indexed in `O(1)` time.

Format details
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix
[2] https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/471374

Answer (score 2):

An efficient way would be to use hash map (for each row) of hash maps (to store elements in each row by column index). Then would be able to access any element in O(1) time.

You can implement all numeric algorithms, like addition and multiplication iterating only through non-zero elements which will give you better complexity then O(N * M) where N and M are number of columns and rows in a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix is sparse, you only need to store the cells that are filled in. A simple lookup of coordinate to value should do. Ideally you should use something with fast lookup like a map O(log n) or a unordered_map O(1).

Comment: But I need to use a linked list and an array.

Comment: Using a linked list or an array will give you O(n) time - slower but definitely tenable for small values of n. If you can sort your array you can perform a binary search with can be done in O (log n) time.